# How do you enable a Rust "crate feature"?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to use [`rand::SmallRng`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.7.2/rand/rngs/struct.SmallRng.html). The documentation says

> This PRNG is **feature-gated**: to use, you must enable the crate feature `small_rng`.

I've been searching and can't figure out how to enable "crate features". The phrase isn't even used anywhere in the Rust docs. This is the best I could come up with:

```toml
[features]
default = ["small_rng"]
```

But I get:

> Feature `default` includes `small_rng` which is neither a dependency nor another feature

Are the docs wrong, or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Specify the dependencies in Cargo.toml like so:

```toml
[dependencies]
rand = { version = "0.7.2", features = ["small_rng"] }
```

Alternatively:

```toml
[dependencies.rand]
version = "0.7.2"
features = ["small_rng"]
```

Both work.

Answer (score 12):

To add a feature you can use. This works even if you have added the crate initially and want to add a feature later

```
cargo add rand -F small_rng
```

Comment: This works even before adding the crate. The `-F` is a shorthand for `--features`.