# How do I serialize and deserialize a graph using Serde with Petgraph?

Tags: graph, rust, serde, petgraph

[The Petgraph documentation](https://docs.rs/petgraph/0.5.0/petgraph/) hints at Serde support. Under "current features":

> serde-1 - Defaults off. Enables serialization for Graph, StableGraph using serde 1.0. May require a more recent version of Rust than petgraph alone.

I can see the file `serde_utils.rs` in the source, but I've found no examples showing how to get Serde support working.

I'm aware of how to [enable an optional crate feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58480205/how-do-you-enable-a-rust-crate-feature). My question is aimed at getting serialization and deserialization to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example:

```rust
use petgraph::graph::UnGraph;

fn main() {
    // Create an undirected graph with `i32` nodes and edges with `()` associated data.
    let g = UnGraph::<i32, ()>::from_edges(&[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (1, 4)]);

    // Serialize it to a JSON string.
    let j = serde_json::to_string(&g).unwrap();

    let i: UnGraph<i32, ()> = serde_json::from_str(&j).unwrap();

    assert!(petgraph::algo::is_isomorphic(&i, &g));
}
```

All you need is in the [documentation](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/).