# Cannot find tokio::main macro?

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-cargo, rust-tokio

I am creating a sample Rust project in my Windows system to download a file by HTTP GET request in async mode.

My code is as follows (same as [the code](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-cookbook/web/clients/download.html) mentioned in the Rust Cookbook):

```rust
extern crate error_chain;
extern crate tempfile;
extern crate tokio;
extern crate reqwest;

use error_chain::error_chain;
use std::io::copy;
use std::fs::File;
use tempfile::Builder;

error_chain! {
     foreign_links {
         Io(std::io::Error);
         HttpRequest(reqwest::Error);
     }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let tmp_dir = Builder::new().prefix("example").tempdir()?;
    let target = "https://www.rust-lang.org/logos/rust-logo-512x512.png";
    let response = reqwest::get(target).await?;

    let mut dest = {
        let fname = response
            .url()
            .path_segments()
            .and_then(|segments| segments.last())
            .and_then(|name| if name.is_empty() { None } else { Some(name) })
            .unwrap_or("tmp.bin");

        println!("file to download: '{}'", fname);
        let fname = tmp_dir.path().join(fname);
        println!("will be located under: '{:?}'", fname);
        File::create(fname)?
    };
    let content =  response.text().await?;
    copy(&mut content.as_bytes(), &mut dest)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

My Cargo.toml file is:

```
[package]
name = "abcdef"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["xyz"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
error-chain = "0.12.4"
tempfile = "3.1.0"
tokio = "0.2.22"
reqwest = "0.10.8"
```

When I execute `cargo run`, the following errors are displayed:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `main` in `tokio`
  --> src\main.rs:18:10
   |
18 | #[tokio::main]
   |          ^^^^ could not find `main` in `tokio`

error[E0277]: `main` has invalid return type `impl std::future::Future`
  --> src\main.rs:19:20
   |
19 | async fn main() -> Result<()> {
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^ `main` can only return types that implement `
std::process::Termination`
   |
   = help: consider using `()`, or a `Result`

error[E0752]: `main` function is not allowed to be `async`
  --> src\main.rs:19:1
   |
19 | async fn main() -> Result<()> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `main` function is not allowed to be `async`
```

I cross-checked from the Cargo.toml file & `edition = "2018"` was already there. I am unable to figure out the other errors.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You need to enable an extra feature in `tokio` to be able to use `tokio::main`.

Try adding the `full` feature to the `tokio` dependency in your Cargo.toml file:

```
[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "0.2.22", features = ["full"] }
```

This also applies to later versions of Tokio.

Comment: Sorry, but this is the cannonball answer ;-) Shepmaster's is the one to go!

Answer (score 38):

As stated in the documentation for [`tokio::main`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.18.2/tokio/attr.main.html):

> Available on **crate features `rt` and `macros`** only.

You need to add those features to get access to `tokio::main`:

```
[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["rt", "macros"] }
```

This will only allow access to [the single-threaded executor](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.18.2/tokio/runtime/struct.Builder.html#method.new_current_thread), however, so you'd have to use `#[tokio::main(flavor = "current_thread")]`. If you want to use `#[tokio::main]` (which is the same as `#[tokio::main(flavor = "multi_thread")]`, then you need to enable the [multi-threaded executor](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.18.2/tokio/runtime/struct.Builder.html#method.new_multi_thread):

> Available on **crate feature `rt-multi-thread`** only.

```
[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["rt-multi-thread", "macros"] }
```

See also:

- [What is the smallest feature set to enable polling a future with Tokio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66960947/155423)
- [How do you enable a Rust "crate feature"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58480205/155423)

Comment: This is the better answer. Enabling the "full" feature spits errors in my macOS 12.3.X, something about not detecting libc. Your suggestion however worked.