# What is the smallest feature set to enable polling a future with Tokio?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I want to poll an async function:

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    some_function().await;
}
```

I am currently activating all features:

```toml
tokio = { version = "1.4.0", features = ["full"] }
```

which of those are necessary?

```toml
full = [
  "fs",
  "io-util",
  "io-std",
  "macros",
  "net",
  "parking_lot",
  "process",
  "rt",
  "rt-multi-thread",
  "signal",
  "sync",
  "time",
]
```

Comment: Keep turning them off until it won't compile, I guess?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To enable polling a future with Tokio, you need a [`Runtime`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.4.0/tokio/runtime/struct.Runtime.html).

> This is supported on crate feature `rt` only.

```
[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "1.4.0", features = ["rt"] }
```

```rust
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    tokio::runtime::Builder::new_current_thread()
        .build()
        .unwrap()
        .block_on(some_function())
}

async fn some_function() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    Ok(())
}
```

If you want to use the [`tokio::main`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.4.0/tokio/attr.main.html) macro:

> This is supported on crate features `rt` and `macros` only.

```
[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "1.4.0", features = ["rt", "macros"] }
```

```rust
#[tokio::main(flavor = "current_thread")]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    some_function().await
}

async fn some_function() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    Ok(())
}
```

If you want the *exact* syntax you've specified (which is not the "smallest feature set to enable polling a future with Tokio"), then the runtime error guides you:

> The default runtime flavor is `multi_thread`, but the `rt-multi-thread` feature is disabled.

```
[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "1.4.0", features = ["rt", "rt-multi-thread", "macros"] }
```

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    some_function().await
}

async fn some_function() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    Ok(())
}
```

See also:

- [How do I synchronously return a value calculated in an asynchronous Future in stable Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52521201/155423)
- [How do I execute an async/await function without using any external dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56252798/155423)

Comment: thanks. I tried that before and I thought it wasn't possible because I got ``main` function is not allowed to be `async``. Is it possible to import one more thing just to make `#[tokio::main]` work?

Comment: @Gatonito To use the `tokio::main` attribute you need the `"macros"` feature, and the default runtime is multithreaded so you'll want `"rt-multi-thread"` instead of `"rt"`.

Comment: Could you add an example on how to keep `fn main` non async? I'm aware of `block_on` but I'm curious if there's a way to do like `std::thread::spawn` for an async-fn and poll it to be finished/join it without `await`. I'm make a DLL and I can't have `async` exported functions for C FFI reasons.

Comment: @BrandonRos the examples here are just that. While the source code says `async fn main`, the `#[tokio::main]` procedural macro rewrites that to `fn main`.