# How to enable unstable Rust feature str_split_once?

Tags: rust

I'm having a hard time figuring out where do I need to write something to enable this feature.

I tried adding `#![feature(str_split_once)]` to the file where I'm using it but nothing happens. By Googling I found [How do you enable a Rust "crate feature"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58480205/how-do-you-enable-a-rust-crate-feature) but after adding

```
[features]
default = ["str_split_once"]
```

to Cargo it doesn't build with

> Caused by:   feature `default` includes `str_split_once` which is
> neither a dependency nor another feature

Comment: [Cannot reproduce, make sure you're using nightly.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=778fb2cb60bd0e2d8b351f02dbd29634) Also make sure you also add them to the root source file of the crate (`lib.rs` or `main.rs`).

Comment: `str_split_once` is a language feature, not a crate feature. It has nothing to do with Cargo.toml.

Answer (score 3):

> I tried adding #![feature(str_split_once)] to the file where I'm using it but nothing happens.

I guess there's not really "nothing happens", but there was a warning similar to this one:

```
warning: crate-level attribute should be in the root module
 --> src/lib.rs:2:5
  |
2 |     #![feature(str_split_once)]
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4a66c8683503a06f6205cc7dae8531cb)

Just add this line at the beginning of `lib.rs` and/or `main.rs`, build with nightly, and it should work:

```
#![feature(str_split_once)]

fn main() {
    // prints Some(("test1", "test2 test3"))
    println!("{:?}", "test1 test2 test3".split_once(" "));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=69699fa6041ed976823be11070d430f4)

Comment: Turns out we use stable so I cannot use this feature because I have to use nightly to be able to use it

Comment: Yes, every language feature is available only on nightly, since it may change in any version.