# can't import JsBox from Neon::types

Tags: rust, neon-bindings

For some reason, I can't use JsBox. I am using the 0.8.2 crate I get the flowing error

unresolved import `neon::types::JsBox`

Comment: Looking at the [documentation of the neon crate, version 0.8.2](https://docs.rs/neon/0.8.2/neon/), there is no `JsBox` anywhere.

Comment: I see that the documentation of the `types` module still mentions `JsBox`, but the link is dead. It probably existed in an earlier version and has been removed.

Comment: it seems, that it still exists in [this version](https://docs.rs/neon/0.8.2-napi/neon/types/struct.JsBox.html)

Comment: Looks like you [need to enable the `napi-1` feature](https://docs.rs/neon/0.8.2-napi/src/neon/types/mod.rs.html#76-77).

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: [How do you enable a Rust “crate feature”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58480205/how-do-you-enable-a-rust-crate-feature)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/neon-bindings/neon/blob/0.8.2/src/types/mod.rs#L76), `neon::types::JsBox` seems to be only available with the new N-API backend. You can find a migration guide [here](https://github.com/neon-bindings/neon/blob/main/MIGRATION_GUIDE.md). This is probably the most relevant part:

> #### Enabling the N-API backend
>
> To enable the N-API backend, you need to:
>
> 1. Remove `build.rs` from the project directory and `build = "build.rs"` from the `Cargo.toml`. The N-API backend does not require a Cargo build script.
> 2. Disable the default features (for now, the default features select the legacy > backend) by setting `default-features = false`; and
> 3. Enable the appropriate feature flag in your `Cargo.toml` to select the N-API version you need support for (each N-API version N uses the feature flag `"napi-N"`, for example `"napi-4"` for N-API version 4).
>
> As a rule, you should choose the **oldest version of N-API that has the APIs you need.** (We will be adding N-API version requirements to the Neon API docs to make this clearer in the future.) You can consult the [official N-API feature matrix](https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html#n_api_node_api_version_matrix) to see which N-API versions come with various versions of Node.
>
> ```
> [dependencies.neon]
> version = "0.8.2"
> default-features = false
> features = ["napi-4"]
> ```